# Two digit division from string

Tags: c++, division

I want to devide a string value i'm getting. Lets say i have a set of customers. Each customer is set to have a number of sheets in a letter. I have two string variables:

sheetsPerCustomer and totalPagescustomer

Currently it looks like this:

```
Customer A:
sheetsPerCustomer = "01"  totalPagescustomer "06" // page 1 of 3
sheetsPerCustomer = "02"  totalPagescustomer "06" // page 2 of 3
sheetsPerCustomer = "03"  totalPagescustomer "06" // page 3 of 3
```

I have to devide totalPagescustomer as total pages are 3 and not 6. It should look like this:

```
sheetsPerCustomer = "01"  totalPagescustomer "03" // page 1 of 3
sheetsPerCustomer = "02"  totalPagescustomer "03" // page 2 of 3
sheetsPerCustomer = "03"  totalPagescustomer "03" // page 3 of 3
```

A straight of division does not work as the "0" will be lost if i'm converting the string to int for division. I need to keep the leftside number as total pages can be 10, 20 etc so i need two digits. Is there a way to archive this?

Comment: Question is unclear - can you give concrete examples of what results you want from the above example ?

Comment: Sorry. Updated the post.

Comment: So you just want to divide the `totalPagescustomer` by 2 in each case, yes ? But you want to keep the result as 2 digits ? So `06` becomes `03`, `10` becomes `05`, `20` becomes `10` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a similar approach:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char buf[16];
   int j = 7;
   sprintf(buf, "%02d", j);
   cout << "Result is " << buf << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This prints `Result is 07`.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself the hassle and use integers. It makes your intentions much clearer. If you are trying to use something 'like' an int then maybe you should be using an int.

If you then need to display a 2 digit number you can do something like this:

```
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << sheetsPerCustomer  << std::endl;
```